# Delete multiple tables in a single query with join in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

This is my query in rails, I want to delete entries from `feed` and `feed mappings` table which match certain conditions in a single query, If I use `destroy_all` it deletes items one by one, first it will delete feed and then feed_mappings for each entry, whereas If I can just change the `Select` statement on the resulting query into `Delete feed, feed_mappings` I can delete everything in one query. Help me solve this problem in a single query.

```
Feed.joins(:feed_mappings)
          .joins('inner join notifications on notifications.id = feed_mappings.source_id')
          .joins('inner join user_feedbacks on user_feedbacks.source_id = notifications.picked_for_company')
          .joins('inner join user_feedback_contexts on user_feedback_contexts.user_feedback_id = user_feedbacks.id')
          .where(user_feedbacks: {source_type: 'Company', user_id: user.id},
                 user_feedback_contexts: {context: 'block'},
                 notifications: {user_id: user.id},
                 feed_mappings: {source_type: 'Notifications::Notification'})
```

This generates

```
SELECT `feeds`.* FROM   `feeds` 
   INNER JOIN `feed_mappings` 
           ON `feed_mappings`.`feed_id` = `feeds`.`id` 
   INNER JOIN notifications 
           ON notifications.id = feed_mappings.source_id 
   INNER JOIN user_feedbacks 
           ON user_feedbacks.source_id = notifications.picked_for_company 
   INNER JOIN user_feedback_contexts 
           ON user_feedback_contexts.user_feedback_id = user_feedbacks.id 
   WHERE  `user_feedbacks`.`source_type` = 'Company' 
   AND `user_feedbacks`.`user_id` = 6 
   AND `user_feedback_contexts`.`context` = 'block' 
   AND `notifications`.`user_id` = 6 
   AND `feed_mappings`.`source_type` = 'Notifications::Notification'
```

What I want instead

```
DELETE `feeds`, `feed_mappings` FROM   `feeds` 
   INNER JOIN `feed_mappings` 
           ON `feed_mappings`.`feed_id` = `feeds`.`id` 
   INNER JOIN notifications 
           ON notifications.id = feed_mappings.source_id 
   INNER JOIN user_feedbacks 
           ON user_feedbacks.source_id = notifications.picked_for_company 
   INNER JOIN user_feedback_contexts 
           ON user_feedback_contexts.user_feedback_id = user_feedbacks.id 
   WHERE  `user_feedbacks`.`source_type` = 'Company' 
   AND `user_feedbacks`.`user_id` = 6 
   AND `user_feedback_contexts`.`context` = 'block' 
   AND `notifications`.`user_id` = 6 
   AND `feed_mappings`.`source_type` = 'Notifications::Notification'
```

Comment: Which database? A real foreign key inside the database with `on delete cascade` might be an option.

Comment: What's the relationship between feed and feed_mappings? Could we see their models?

Comment: @JohnSkilesSkinner `feed_mapping` has a foreign key named `feed_id` to feeds table

Comment: @muistooshort mysql, on delete cascade is a nice idea, but it might interfere with the hooks that we already have in place on the Models.

Comment: If you have hooks then AR is going to have to load all the dependent models in order to run the hooks in the environment they expect. There are reasons that logic often belongs in the database.

Answer (score 0):

All the joins complicates things, but does the following work?

```
Feed.joins(:feed_mappings)
          .joins('inner join notifications on notifications.id = feed_mappings.source_id')
          .joins('inner join user_feedbacks on user_feedbacks.source_id = notifications.picked_for_company')
          .joins('inner join user_feedback_contexts on user_feedback_contexts.user_feedback_id = user_feedbacks.id')
          .where(user_feedbacks: {source_type: 'Company', user_id: user.id},
                 user_feedback_contexts: {context: 'block'},
                 notifications: {user_id: user.id},
                 feed_mappings: {source_type: 'Notifications::Notification'}).delete_all

FeedMappings.joins('inner join notifications on notifications.id = feed_mappings.source_id')
            .joins('inner join user_feedbacks on user_feedbacks.source_id = notifications.picked_for_company')
            .joins('inner join user_feedback_contexts on user_feedback_contexts.user_feedback_id = user_feedbacks.id')
            .where(user_feedbacks: {source_type: 'Company', user_id: user.id},
                   user_feedback_contexts: {context: 'block'},
                   notifications: {user_id: user.id},
                   feed_mappings: {source_type: 'Notifications::Notification'}).delete_all
```

Comment: These are two different queries, I want to do it in a single query, since we know it's possible in raw sql.